# youtube playVideoAt() doesnt play on first click

Tags: javascript, video, web, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I've got a youtube player with some hyperlinks next to it that link to different videos in the playlist.  I'm selecting each video by calling playVideoAt with the index.  This works just fine except it doesn't work on the first click.

Here's the code where I'm setting up the player (basically copy/pasted from their docs)

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('youtube-player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640'
    });
}
```

and playing the video

```
$('.video-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).attr("data-i");
    player.playVideoAt(index);
})
```